# Problems upgrading MacPro to Mountain Lion

Tags: osx-mountain-lion, mac-pro

I am trying to upgrade my MacPro to Mountain Lion.  After researching online it seems my model does not have a 64 bit compatible GPU.  Is it possible to upgrade the GPU or would the entire motherboard need to be replaced?

The MacPro is a late 2007 model MacPro 2,1

Comment: You need to provide a lot more information, including the particular model, CPU, etc.

Comment: +1 for @RandolphWest. We do need your exact Macbook Pro make, for example (1,2) and year of manufacture (2006) etc. so we know what your exact configuration is, and how to go about helping you!

Comment: Updated question with year and model.